# Getting vim with yapf to work with anaconda environments

Tags: formatting, filetype-python

I'm trying to figure out how to get yapf to use my current conda environment when resolving imports. Basically, I just see a ton of the following errors:

```
physics.py|6 col 1 error| [import-error] Unable to import 'torch' 
physics.py|8 col 1 error| [import-error] Unable to import 'torch.autograd'
```

For autoformatting, my .vimrc currently just contains:

```
autocmd FileType python AutoFormatBuffer yapf
```

and yapf has been installed using pathogen. If using yapf is too much of a burden, is there some other autoformatter that works seamlessly with conda?

Answer (score 1):

In general, vim still doesn't handle anaconda environments nicely. I don't know if you open vim from the terminal, after you activate the environment, or not, so it's hard to tell what's going on, but I will tell you what I do:

I use Neovim, and open it from the terminal after activating my environment.
Inside init.vim (==.vimrc) I use the variable `$CONDA_PREFIX` to get to the environment directory. My pylint for example is set up like this:

```
let PYLINT = $CONDA_PREFIX
let PYLINT .= '/bin/pylint'
```

And I use `PYLINT` as the executable path for Neomake to run it on each save:

```
let g:neomake_python_mypylint_maker = {
    \ 'args': [
    \ '--output-format', 'text',
    \ '--reports', 'no',
    \ '--msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg}"',
    \ '--rcfile=/home/abeka/workspace/pylint.cfg'
    \ ],
    \ 'errorformat':
    \ '%A%f:%l:%c:%t: %m,' .
    \ '%A%f:%l: %m,' .
    \ '%A%f:(%l): %m,' .
    \ '%-Z%p^%.%#,' .
    \ '%-G%.%#',
    \ 'exe': PYLINT,
    \ 'postprocess': function('neomake#makers#ft#python#PylintEntryProcess'),
\ }

autocmd! BufWritePost ~/workspace/*/*.py Neomake mypylint
```

I hope this gives you enough data to tweak your settings accordingly.